# Every command fails with "command not found" after changing .bash_profile?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was updating my .bash_profile, and unfortunetly I made a few updates and now I am getting:

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
-bash: tar: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
-bash: find: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: /preexec.sh.lib: No such file or directory
-bash: preexec_install: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: git: command not found
```

My bash_profile actually pulls in other .sh files (sources them) so I am not exactly sure which modification may have caused this.

Now if I even try and to a list of files, I get:

```
>ls
-bash: ls: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: git: command not found
```

**Any tips on how to trace the source of the error, and how to be able to use the terminal for basic things like listing files etc?**

Comment: What happens if you use the full path like so: /bin/ls ?
And what sorts of changes were you making?

Comment: Yes, paste your .bash_profile

Comment: /bin/ls lists the files, but then I see these 2 lines below it: `-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: git: command not found`

Comment: In case your problem was with `/etc/environment`, use the following command (in centos 6): `ssh -t root@<server-ip> "/bin/bash -c '/bin/mv /etc/environment /tmp/'"`

Comment: For VM, after reboot, it goes to "Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.", enter `xfs_repair -v -L /dev/dm-0` and then `reboot` seems fix the issue.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It looks to me that at one point or another you are overwriting the default `PATH` environment variable. The type of errors you have, indicates that `PATH` does not contain `/bin`, where the above commands (including `bash`) reside.

For example, if you do

```
PATH=/home/user/bin
```

instead of

```
PATH="$PATH":/home/user/bin
```

Comment: I did do this at one point: `export PATH=PATH:EC2_HOME/bin`

Comment: You have to use '$' in the second PATH string -  `export PATH=$PATH:EC2_HOME/bin`

Comment: strange how 'ec2-describe-regions' doesn't work, even though it is in my path, yet this works: $EC2_HOME/bin/ec2-describe-regions  I did a source reload also....

Comment: doing a echo $PATH, I see it is repeated 3 times: `EC2_HOME/bin:EC2_HOME/bin:EC2_HOME/bin`  how can I fix this, reboot?  source'ing it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: actually me running source seems to be adding a new one each time??

Comment: Look, we don't know what you are doing, what other files you are sourcing, what is in them. And yes, every time you source the file, you *append* things to your path (which is fine, because normally .bash_profile will get read only once). Go through it one by one and see what happens. Also, isn't EC2_HOME a variable? If yes, then you should precede it with a `$` like this: `export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin`

Comment: This was my problem. In order to reset my PATH so I could go into my bash profile and erase the bad PATH line in my `~/.bash_profile` I had to reset my PATH by doing:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: I lose count of how much times I stucked into that problem and how much times this answer helped me a lot

Comment: @Lauren omg thank you!

Comment: Wow, I can't believe after years of using linux I committed the error of writing `PATH="$1"` in my convenience script.

Comment: @J.M. Janzen
  Ha-ha, just did the same and spent half an hour for debug ))))

Answer (score 25):

One way to begin debugging your bash script would be to start a subshell with the -x option:

```
$ bash --login -x
```

This will show you every command, and its arguments, which is executed when starting that shell.

The --login option is specified because .bash_profile is read by login shells.  Further information on debugging bash scripts can be found here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html.

Ultimately, I think that January's suggestion will work for you, but that link is worth a read for future problems.

Comment: got this: -bash: bash: command not found

Comment: Fantastic solution. Easy and simple for spotting just where the error is. Thanks! But there seems to be a "problem". After I use the commands, any executed command is displayed in the console. Is there a way to turn it off other than restarting the shell? I'm not really versed in bash.

Answer (score 13):

I may have found the problem. It worked for me, and it might work for you...

I was defaulting with my editor to Windows (LF/CR) saves. Since I use both systems, it seemed logical. When I needed to mess with my `.bash_profile`, I realized after commenting out and tryig things that nothing worked. I changed my saves to OS X format (CR only) and voilà! No more "command not found" in the terminal!

It may just be that easy!

Comment: Very subtle thing that was driving me crazy.  Thanks for adding this answer!

Comment: This was what I was experiencing! Thanks. Quick tip is using this command to convert files on your unix environment: `$ dos2unix .bash_profile`

Comment: Are you sure that's what you did? Since OS X is Unix it uses Unix-style line endings with a single linefeed (LF) character, not carriage return (CR). The only popular operating system that used the latter were OS 9 and prior and Linux/Ubuntu applications would be quite confused by it.

Answer (score 6):

After I couldn't re-run . ~/.bash_profile or any usual commands like whoami, grep, etc.
I figured a way to just re-export the required paths:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/easy/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

This should work in most systems, although some of these paths are not present in all Linux packages. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have found the answer to the problem if not for you then for others who have a similar problem. My answer to this is that I do not have a `.bash_profile`.

So I was searching all over the web and I found the solution. Which is basically open the terminal, type `touch ~/.bash_profile` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That fixed my problems. Hope it does the same for you

Comment: LOL... -bash: touch: command not found

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem like you. I can't use many popular command (`ls`, `vi/vim`, ..) and can't edit `/root/.bashrc` when I log in with `su` into root.

Finally. I found the solution for this problem. Just login root with command:

```
su -m
```

After that, you can use

```
vim /root/.bashrc
```

to edit PATH.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You may have missed a $ while exporting PATH. You should open the .bash_profile in TextEdit. If you can't find the file in the directory, press Command + Shift + > to show hidden files.

Then make correction to the PATH and then save.

In the directory on Terminal, type: source .bash_profile.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, finally i was able to edit my bash_profile file.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem:

If I put in lxterminal:

```
set | grep "jerom/bash"
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jerom/bash/
```

if I entered exactly the same command in tty2 I got:

```
set | grep "jerom/bash"
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jerom/bash\r
```

\r means DOS end of line, so I opened file `~/.bashrc` and change the ends of lines in Krusader to unix style. And its working already!!! :-)

The DOS EOLs make spourious problems also in bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem just now after I changed the `.bash_profile`.
And I want to change it back but now I can't, because I lost all the commands, especially the nano command and the vim command, so I can't open the .bash_profile with command. And the `.bash_profile` is a hidden file I can't open it with the Finder.

**So I need to find a way to open the .bash_profile file.**
After I tried many ways I found that I can use **Atom**, because Atom can read all files in a project folder, include the hidden files.
So just open Atom, and select the `File -> Open`, choose `<yourusername>` folder, and then, all hidden files is showing on the Atom's tree view, include the `.bash_profile`!!
After I removed the last modification and reopen the Terminal, all commands came back! :)